# Android Studio Manifest Error And Disabled Run Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there a lot of this kind of questions but none of those answers worked for me.
I opened an existing project in android studio and saw my run button grayed out. Then check the manifest and I saw  that

```
android:value="@bool/boolean_true" />
```

even this statement gives error message like Cannot resolve @bool/boolean_true .

I couldn't overcome this porblem, any advice?

Comment: It turns out I accidently opened my whole project(with web part) that is why run button was grey. And after I open the right part, I did a mvn clean install and now everthing is fine

Answer (score 0):

Create `res/values/bool.xml` and add this in that file `<bool name="boolean_true">true</bool>`

Comment: My problem is not with bools. I have 190 error just like this. everything is red :/

Answer (score 0):

Just select the app from the dropdown which is just left to Run button in Android Studio.otherwise just show the log.

Comment: There is just one option and it is edit configuration

Comment: I am not sure where is it or what is it

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> check this tag